# To peek into kernel by socket failure with levels and kill-9

Tags: sockets, crash, computer-science, signals, kill

Kill-9-signalling all postgres processes ignite errors immediately after the command:

```
$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

## Long-term Computer Science problem

*The aim of the test is to simulate a serious fatal error, peeking into kernel due to the socket failure. It is good practise in cases such as crash-recovery.*

1. Does it have something to do with the levels, zero and three, of x86?
2. What did the 9-killing do to things such as kernel and fs?
3. What is wrong with the socket?
4. What did happen to files during the signaling, related to side effects?

Comment: (removed a side-discussion about a: editing posts, and b: the volume of notification messages in SO; these were not related directly to this post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This more a Server Fault kind of question, but try running psql like this:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

When you install PostgreSQL, there's no user account created for your current user, so you'd have to create one.

That can be achieved like this (where *masi* is the wanted username):

```
sudo -u postgres createuser -sdrPE masi
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does it have something to do with the
>   levels, zero and three, of x86?

No.

> What did the 9-killing do to things
>   such as kernel and fs?

Nothing - though the database files of postgresql might have been left in an inconsistent state.

> Has the failure with reinstalling
>   anything to do with side effects

No (?).

Sending signal 9 to a process simply forces it to exit immediately. For a database server that can be a bit fatal if it was in the middle of altering the data files/storage - leaving them in an inconsistent state.

It sounds like you either haven't removed *everything* from your old postgresql installation, or you haven't configured the server properly after reinstalling it.

Comment: A note: PostgreSQL will *not* become inconsistent or corrupted from a kill -9. It will perform crash recovery on startup, and be perfectly fine to use. It'll just take a little bit longer to start.